# mergin one stored procedure to another in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@carid nvarchar(50) =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode,t.Status
from Transaction_tbl t 
 where t.TBarcode=@carid
end
```

my output :

```
TBarcode             Status
51891044554          1
```

I want to show one more column depend upon my status.so i worte one function like this:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[keyloc](@status numeric(18,0)) RETURNS varchar(50)
as
begin
declare 
@keylocation  Varchar(50) 
if @status=1
select @keylocation= e1.Ename from Transaction_tbl t left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e1
ON e1.ECode = t.ECode AND t.Status = 1 or e1.Ecode=t.DelEcode and t.Status=4
return @keylocation
end
```

then i try to execute my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@carid nvarchar(50) =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode,[dbo].[keyloc](t.Status)
from Transaction_tbl t 
 where t.TBarcode=@carid
end
```

but my output is getting wrong:

```
TBarcode            
51891044554          Null
```

what is wrong with my code? my expected output is this:

```
TBarcode             Status  key location
51891044554          1       Raheem.
```

how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you made a left join in your function, try this:

```
select @keylocation= e1.Ename 
from Transaction_tbl t
join EmployeeMaster_tbl e1
ON e1.ECode = t.ECode AND t.Status = 1 
or e1.Ecode=t.DelEcode and t.Status=4
```

Answer (score 0):

In your altered procedure you forgot (?) to include the status field, which is why it isn't included. This:

```
select t.TBarcode,[dbo].[keyloc](t.Status)
```

Should be:

```
select t.TBarcode, t.Status, [dbo].[keyloc](t.Status) as 'Key location'
```

if you want a column for `Status`too and a heading for `Key location`

Why your function returns null I really can't say, is the data correct? Have you tried executing it alone to see that it returns the expected output? It could be that the WHERE clause in the function evaluates in the wrong way. Try making the evaluation more explicit by putting the predicates in parenthesis like:

```
ON (e1.ECode = t.ECode AND t.Status = 1) or (e1.Ecode=t.DelEcode and t.Status=4)
```

If that is the way it should be evaluated.

Also, is the `Status`really an `numeric(18,0)`value, if not you might want to change the function parameter to something more appropriate (like smallint or int).

Comment: sir my data is correct.but i am getting key location table is null

Comment: i got out put .i changed left join to join.now am getting out put